# Como copiar copiar o maior arquivo de pasta para outra usando bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Dentro de um diretório com vários subdiretórios consigo buscar todos os arquivos .py, ver só quais tem datetime e me mostrar só o maior deles. Usando o find, grep, ls e head, porém quando tento copiar o output do head, no caso o maior arquivo py. que possue datetime, da erro! Na verdade queria copiar esse arquivo para usar o grep nele novamente para encontrar todas as classes e as funções desse arquivo. Se alguém tem alguma dica, agradeço!

Comment: baseado numas respostas do stackoverflow en cp 'ls -S /path/to/folder | head -1
'  /caminho/da/copia

Answer (score 0):

Com o auxílio de alguns comandos, dá pra achar o maior arquivo assim:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -f 2 -d' '
```

Explicando por partes:

- `find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n"` acha todos os arquivos que são do tipo `file` e imprime o tamanho do arquivo e o path separados por um espaço
- `sort -n` ordena a saída do `find` por tamanho dos arquivos
- `tail -n1` pega a última linha do `sort` que é o arquivo com maior tamanho
- `cut -f 2 -d' '` da última linha, pega o segundo campo usando espaço como separador

Tendo o nome do arquivo, basta fazer o `grep` que seja necessário, inclusive é possível interpolar os comandos anterior com o `grep` e fazer tudo em uma linha só:

```
grep <padrão_procurado> "$(find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -f 2 -d' ')"
```